# How do I use sed to insert a line at the top of my file?

Tags: shell, sed, files, scripting

I'm using bash shell on Amazon Linux.  I'm trying to insert a line at the top of my file so I have

```
header_line="first_line_of_file"
...
    sed -i "1 i\$header_line" /tmp/$file_title
```

However what is actually appearing at the top of my file is

```
$header_line
```

How do I tell sed not to interpret my variable literally but rather use the value from the variable to insert at the top of my file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using GNU or `busybox`, `sed`, then you should be able to do

```
sed -i "1i $header_line" "/tmp/$file_title"
```

The issue you had was due to escaping the `$` from the shell so that it didn't recognise `$header_line` as a variable.

With NetBSD or OpenBSD `sed` (also with FreeBSD and macOS but you need a space between the `-i` and `''` there):

```
sed -i'' "1i\\
$header_line
" "/tmp/$file_title"
```

BSD `sed`, like traditional `sed` implementations, and as specified by POSIX, requires a `\` and a literal newline after the `i` command, and since we're double quoting, we need to escape the `\` from the shell.

An alternative would be to use `cat`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$header_line" | cat - "/tmp/$file_title" >new_file && mv new_file "/tmp/$file_title"
```

This also bypasses issues with backslashes in the value of `$header_line` mentioned by Stéphane Chazelas in comments below.

Comment: It's not only BSD `sed`, it's every `sed` but GNU `sed` (or `ssed` of the same family) and `busybox` sed. Using that standard syntax (GNU `-i`/BSD `-i ''` remain non-standard though) also makes it work for values of `$header_line` that starts with blanks (backslashes remain a problem).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the edit, but I hope you don't mind me rolling it back. OpenBSD `sed` does _not_ like a space between `-i` and its argument.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Out of all the problematic portability issues between GNU and BSD tools, the `-i` flag of `sed` is the most irritating.

Comment: `sed -i''` is the same as `sed -i`. FreeBSD, OS/X won't take `sed -i'' 'code'`. But, yes you're right, apparently NetBSD and OpenBSD recently added support for `-i` and did it à la GNU instead of à la FreeBSD ([NetBSD at least imported the FreeBSD code and modified it to make the argument to `-i` optional](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/sed/main.c.diff?r1=1.22&r2=1.1.1.2)). I wasn't aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: [OpenBSD also acknowledge taking `-i` from FreeBSD but changing the option to be optional](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/sed/main.c.diff?r1=1.18&r2=1.19) (2015, a year after NetBSD). Right thing for them to do as the GNU usage is now prevalent and similar to `perl`'s where it comes from, but I don't expect FreeBSD will change theirs as that would break backward compatibility (FreeBSD `sed` has had `sed -i ''` since 2002 (before GNU added `-i` (3.95 a few months later that year))).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the research. I'm leaving `-i''` in there. I'm growing tired of the various flavours of `-i`. The flag should be avoided, IMHO.